# What is necessary to fire Tracker's autorun function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-tracker

I have such an example Meteor app:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Things = new Mongo.Collection('things');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(() => {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
      console.log('AUTORUN');
    });
    Meteor.subscribe('things');
    render(<div>Hello world</div>, document.getElementById('app'));
  });
} else if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('things', function() {
    return Things.find({});
  });
}
```

I expected that while modifying one of documents in my `Things` collection the autorun function should be fired, but it isn't. So my question is: what conditions should be met to fire autorun function after modifying subscribed data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes here:

1. A `Tracker.autorun` detects changes only within the function that it wraps (the one as its argument). Here you have only a `console.log`, which is not a reactive source that the autorun can watch.
2. There is a difference between the Pub/Sub mechanism and the documents themselves. Your Subscription will not change when you modify documents. But if you place a Collection *query* within your autorun, then the cursor returned by the query is a reactive source that is changed when the documents are modified.

So you could do something like:

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('things');

    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        Things.find(); // <= Reactive source
        console.log('AUTORUN');
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks - so as I can see, `autorun` function runs only when inside it some data are physically (with `fetch` or `findOne`) taken? And do I understand well that this reactivity is possible only in that case or are they some other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Anything that is a _reactive source_. Typically [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) and [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html), besides a Collection cursor.